# Issue with javascript escape, encodeURI and encodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript, ajax, escaping

My application sends data from javascript to my servlet using ajax POST request and that data contains special characters as well. I am sending this data after executing javascript `escape()` over the data as my content can also contains URL's.

The problem is that I do not get correct data at my servlet end and I am suspecting that `escape` is creating the issue.

I tried following in my javascript code :

```
alert(escape("»"));
alert(unescape(escape("»")));

alert(encodeURI("»"));
alert(decodeURI(encodeURI("»")));

alert(encodeURIComponent("»"));
alert(decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent("»")));
```

I do not get correct alert when I am unescaping the escape string, As seen by the code, I have also tried using encodeURI, encodeURIComponent and their respective decoding methods.

How should I send the data from javascript so that all of the special character and other part of the content (like URL's) are received properly.

Comment: All of those examples work perfectly for me. What do you get in the alert?

Comment: @Pointy my bad that I didn't tested it in a separate .html file, it works fine there, but when I try it from my application, it shows `Â»`. Any idea on what might be the issue? My jsp uses :`<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>` But the separate .html file is working fine with this encoding.

Comment: My bad again, this charset encoding was the issue, I don't know why I was trying to put jsp directive on html :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

was the issue, Changed it to UTF-8, works fine now.